# Using multiple `useState()` states together

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks

I'm using an asynchronous API call to fetch some template data in a parent record. (The child components will be switched around based on choices made in other children.)

The template data is quite large, so I only want to fetch it once. Further, I was trying to pass in only the minimum props required by each child. Some only need the names of the templates, others need the appropriate group array. I'm therefore trying to do the work in the parent element. I seem to have run into some confusion about setting state.

---

### Edit

I'm calling `useEffect` with no params so that it executes on load. I'm expecting that the first `setTemplates()` will set the `templates` state variable, so that I can use it in the next call to `setTemplateChoices()` and set the `templateChoices` state AT THE SAME TIME.

---

```
// working version
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function ParentComponent() {
  const [templates, setTemplates] = useState([])
  const [templateChoices, setTemplateChoices] = useState([])

  // this will actually be fetched from within the `useEffect()` call - 
  // I'm just putting it here to show structure and make it testable
  const defaultTemplates = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Form 1', },    // plus - groups: [ {}, {} ... ], etc.
    { id: 2, name: 'Form 2', },    // plus - groups: [ {}, {} ... ], etc.
    { id: 3, name: 'Form 3', },    // plus - groups: [ {}, {} ... ], etc.
  ]

  useEffect(() => {
    setTemplates(defaultTemplates)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Templates</h2>
      {templates.map(template => (
        <p>{template.name}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
// non-working version
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function ParentComponent() {
  const [templates, setTemplates] = useState([])
  const [templateChoices, setTemplateChoices] = useState([])

  const defaultTemplates = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Form 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Form 2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Form 3' },
  ]

  useEffect(() => {
    setTemplates(defaultTemplates)
    setTemplateChoices(templates.map(template => template.name))
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Template Choices</h2>
      {templateChoices.map(choice => (
        <p>{choice}</p>
      ))}
      <p>Children go here depending on step</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I tried using an async and immediate execution to no avail:

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function doWork() {
    await setTemplates(defaultTemplates)
    await setTemplateChoices(templates.map(template => template.name))
  }
  doWork()
}, [])
```

I even tried separting them into two useEffect calls:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setTemplates(defaultTemplates)
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  setTemplateChoices(templates.map(template => template.name))
}, [templates])
```

Still no joy. Why aren't `templateChoices` being set?

Comment: The solution what you shared with the separated `useEffect()`s just working fine on my end.

Comment: you need to provide some more information, your second solution with two separate useEffects seems reasonable and should work - what exactly doesn't seem to work?

Comment: The issue is that whilst `setTemplates()` does indeed seem to set the templates when useEffect executes, I can't then immediately use the `templates` state variable in the call to `setTemplateChoices()` :-(

Comment: I apologise for wasting everyone's time. One bloodied forehead and ruined desk later... turns out, yes the two separate `useEffect()` calls work perfectly - but I *swear* that they didn't the first 4 times I tried them. I'm now picking through the commits to see where I went wrong. Again, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using `useEffect` because you are loading data from somewhere else AND some factor in your query may need to be automatically refreshed due to a variable change.

If not, you should have directly set the state (ie `useState(defaultQuery) or useState(() => defaultQuery)`). This will only call it once when the component loads.

The reason your first sample doesn't work is due to template not being updated immediately. It requires a refresh. You could use useEffect twice but it's inefficient. The easier solution would be

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTemplates(defaultTemplates);
    setTemplateChoices(defaultTemplates.map(template => template.name));
}, [defaultTemplates]);
```

Answer (score 0):

put default in useState:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function ParentComponent() {
  const [templates, setTemplates] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: 'Form 1', },    // plus - groups: [ {}, {} ... ], etc.
    { id: 2, name: 'Form 2', },    // plus - groups: [ {}, {} ... ], etc.
    { id: 3, name: 'Form 3', },    // plus - groups: [ {}, {} ... ], etc.
  ])
  const [templateChoices, setTemplateChoices] = useState([])



  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Templates</h2>
      {templates.map(template => (
        <p>{template.name}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone else, separting them into two useEffect calls does in fact work:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setTemplates(defaultTemplates)
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  setTemplateChoices(templates.map(template => template.name))
}, [templates])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would implement this with React using only 1 `useEffect` with the two `setState` calls inside of it.

**PS:** I didn't use async because the snippet doesn't support it very well. But you can use it.

```js
function mockAPI() {

  const defaultTemplates = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Form 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Form 2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Form 3' },
  ];

  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    setTimeout(()=>resolve(defaultTemplates),1000);
  });
}

function App() {

  const [templates, setTemplates] = React.useState(null);
  const [templateChoices, setTemplateChoices] = React.useState([]);
  
  console.log("Rendering App...");
  console.log("templates: " + templates);
  console.log("templateChoices: " + templateChoices);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Running useEffect...");
    if (!templates) {
      console.log("Fetching templates...");
      mockAPI().then((result) => setTemplates(result));
    }
    else {
      console.log("Setting templateChoices...");
      setTemplateChoices(templates.map(template => template.name));
    }
  },[templates]);

  const choiceItems = templateChoices.map((choice,index) => 
    <p key={index}>{choice}</p>
  );

  return(
    templates ?
      templateChoices ?
        <div>
          {choiceItems}
        </div>
      : null
    : <div>Loading templates...</div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Personally, I would use one useEffect to fetch the templates. And, if possible, build whatever you need with it directly inside the body of the function. Or use a different `useEffect` to do it.

Something like this:

```js
function mockAPI() {

  const defaultTemplates = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Form 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Form 2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Form 3' },
  ];

  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    setTimeout(()=>resolve(defaultTemplates),1000);
  });
}

function App() {

  const [templates, setTemplates] = React.useState(null);
  
  console.log("Rendering App...");
  console.log("templates: " + templates);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Running useEffect...");
    console.log("Fetching templates...");
    mockAPI().then((result) => setTemplates(result));
  },[]);
  
  let choiceItems = null;
  
  if (templates) {
    console.log("Building choiceItems..");
    choiceItems = templates.map((template,index) => 
      <p key={index}>{template.name}</p>
    );
  }

  return(
    templates ?
      <div>
        {choiceItems}
      </div>
    : <div>Loading templates...</div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```